# Whatsapp account menu is missing in the facebook business account

Tags: facebook

Please help me to solve the issue.

The issue is, 
After creating a Facebook business account for WhatsApp business API service. I did not found/see the menu of WhatsApp account setting in this. How to enable this menu. Could you please advice?

Comment: This feature is gradually being rolled out and it is not available for everyone at this moment.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad where did you find this information?

Comment: @ChristianFelipe [Info](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2087193751603668)

Answer (score 4):

I am facing this same issue but as per the documentation [here](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2087193751603668), Facebook is releasing this feature gradually and is not currently available to all the users.

> This feature is gradually rolling out and may not be available to you right now.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is this still the same? I mean is it still not available for all users? I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

i know it is a very old post but still people searching for information about this question... it is very simple answer just change the category on your Facebook page.. Whatsapp button will show again

Comment: Can you please explain more? What category should the page be?